# Django carousel gallery with small pictures on the bottom using models.py

Tags: django-templates, bootstrap-5

[Gallery with carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTPSB.png)

I created a gallery like on the attached picture. I have no problem when I am linking picture from hard drive. I can preview those small pictures in main carousel view by clicking on the them and also using controll buttons on carousel.

The problem I have is how to have the same functionality when loading pictures from the model? The small images after click are displayed randomly on main carousel view.
How to link data-bs-slide-to="" ? Or there is another option?

Below code from liniking from hard drive and using database.

````
          <div id="carouselExampleInterval" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                
              
              <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="10000">
                <img src="{% static 'bpage/img/f1r.jpg' %}" class="rounded d-block img-fluid mx-auto"  alt="...">
              </div>

              <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="2000">
                <img src="{% static 'bpage/img/f2r.jpg' %}" class="rounded d-block img-fluid mx-auto" height="600" alt="...">
              </div>

              <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="2000">
                <img src="{% static 'bpage/img/f3r.jpg' %}" class="rounded d-block img-fluid mx-auto" height="600"  alt="...">
              </div>

              <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="2000">
                <img src="{% static 'bpage/img/f4r.jpg' %}" class="rounded d-block img-fluid mx-auto" height="600"  alt="...">
              </div>

            </div>
            <!--rest of the carousel-->
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleInterval" data-bs-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleInterval" data-bs-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


<!--- imagaes below carousel-->


      <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 ">
          <div class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-sm-4">
            <div class="col">
              <img src="{% static 'bpage/img/f1r.jpg' %}"  class="rounded w-100 mt-2" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleInterval" data-bs-slide-to="0">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <img src="{% static 'bpage/img/f2r.jpg' %}"  class="rounded w-100 mt-2" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleInterval" data-bs-slide-to="1">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <img src="{% static 'bpage/img/f3r.jpg' %}"  class="rounded w-100 mt-2" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleInterval" data-bs-slide-to="2">
            </div>
             <div class="col ">
              <img src="{% static 'bpage/img/f4r.jpg' %}"  class="rounded w-100 mt-2" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleInterval" data-bs-slide-to="3">
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>  
    </div> ```

Gallery created with models.py

```<div class="container">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 ">


          <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
        
              {% for product in products %}
        
              <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.first %} active {% endif %}">
                <img src="{{ product.image.url }}" class="rounded d-block img-fluid mx-auto" height="600"  alt="...">
              </div>
             
              {% endfor %}
        
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<!--- imagaes below carousel-->

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 ">
          <div class="row row-cols-sm-4 row-cols-2">
            

              {% for product in products %}
              <img src="{{ product.image.url }}" class="rounded mt-2" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide-to="">

              {% endfor %}

            
          </div>
      </div>  
    </div> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a for loop to get your images from the model? If you are, then you might be able to map it like this:

```
 data-bs-slide-to="{{ forloop.counter |add:"-1" }}
```

Which, assuming you are using a for loop to display every image , will backlink your thumbnails to your images.